# What data type is missing from this addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button that show's how much celsius is 77 Fahrenheit. I understand I can use onclick, and a much simpler approach, but I'm trying to learn addEventListener.

This is what my code looks like at the moment, and it is refusing to return an answer.
I assume I need some var, let, const, or something somewhere.

```html
<body>
  <h1>Farenheit</h1>
  <p id="answer"> hmmm </p>
  <script>
    button.addEventListener('click',
      function toCelsius(f) {
        return (5 / 9) * (f - 32);
      })
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =
      toCelsius(77);
  </script>
  <button>77 farenheit is...</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation (and the examples in it) for `.addEventListener()` in the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) ->[`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Move the script to AFTER the button, give the button an ID and use document.getElementById and instead of return set the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding in how event listeners and callback works. There is no point in returning from a callback in an event listener, because it does not lead to anything. Instead, you will want to perform all the operations you want in the callback itself.

Moreover, your `button` variable is undefined. You will need to select for the `<button>` element before adding an event listener to it.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
function toCelsius(f) {
  return (5/9) * (f-32);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = toCelsius(77);
});
```

```html
<h1>Farenheit</h1>
<p id="answer"> hmmm </p>
<button>77 farenheit is...</button>
```

Comment: Please note that the above code in the snippet  is executed AFTER load of the page using  `window.addEventListener("load",function() { .... })`

Comment: Fundamental misunderstanding is an understatement. I'm very new to java script so thank you very much for clearing things up!